# Copy HTML to UIPasteboard with React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, uipasteboard

I have a simple react-native app that has some functionality to copy HTML to the global clipboard such that it preserves the styling. The expected result is I copy HTML and can paste it into another app with the styling intact. Note, I’m not looking to paste HTML source code, that is easy and can be done simply by copying as a string.

For iOS 13 I made a minor modification to the [react-native clipboard native module](https://github.com/react-native-clipboard/clipboard) to change it from copying plain text to copying HTML. This code worked as expected with iOS 13, but since updating to 14 it doesn't seem to work - no value seems to be present in the clipboard.

**CustomClipboard.m**

```objectivec
#import "CustomClipboard.h"


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>


@implementation CustomClipboard

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
  return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setString:(NSString *)content)
{
  UIPasteboard *clipboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [clipboard setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypeHTML];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getString:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  reject:(__unused RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  UIPasteboard *clipboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  resolve((clipboard.string ? : @""));
}

@end
```

**CustomClipboard.h**

```objectivec
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface CustomClipboard : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

The native module is imported in JS through:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

export default NativeModules.CustomClipboard;
```

And the exposed to the rest of the app via a Clipboard module:

````js
import NativeClipboard from './NativeClipboard';

/**
 * `Clipboard` gives you an interface for setting and getting content from Clipboard on both iOS and Android
 */
export const Clipboard = {
  /**
   * Get content of string type, this method returns a `Promise`, so you can use following code to get clipboard content
   * ```javascript
   * async _getContent() {
   *   var content = await Clipboard.getString();
   * }
   * ```
   */
  getString(): Promise<string> {
    return NativeClipboard.getString();
  },
  /**
   * Set content of string type. You can use following code to set clipboard content
   * ```javascript
   * _setContent() {
   *   Clipboard.setString('hello world');
   * }
   * ```
   * @param the content to be stored in the clipboard.
   */
  setString(content: string) {
    NativeClipboard.setString(content);
  },
};
````

The code all seems to run correctly, but no value is copied to the clipboard. I haven't been able to find any known bugs on this. Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your comments and edits I have updated my answer - please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.andrewhoyer.com/converting-html-to-nsattributedstring-copy-to-clipboard/

The string needed to be converted to RTF before it was put in the clipboard.

```objectivec
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setString:(NSString *)content)
{
  // Source: http://www.andrewhoyer.com/converting-html-to-nsattributedstring-copy-to-clipboard/
  
  UIPasteboard *clipboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

  // Sets up the attributes for creating Rich Text.
  NSDictionary *documentAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      NSRTFTextDocumentType, NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute,
                                      NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute, [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                      nil];
  
   
  // Create the attributed string using options to indicate HTML text and UTF8 string as the source.
  NSAttributedString *atr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                              initWithData: [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              options: @{
                                  NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                  NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                              }
                              documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    
  // Generate the Rich Text data using the attributed string and the previously created attributes.
  NSData *rtf = [atr dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [atr length]) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:nil];
  
  // Set the Rich Text to the clipboard using an RTF Type
  // Note that this requires <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h> to be imported
  [clipboard setData:rtf forPasteboardType:(NSString*)kUTTypeRTF];
      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This is the second attempt. Earlier I understood you wanted to copy and paste the HTML as text but after your comments and edits to the question I now understand that you have some text that you format using HTML and you want to paste that text while retaining the formatting.

More or less as shown below.

[image: HTML Paster]

This also illustrates how to wire it up in storyboard. Here is the code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel    * statusLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView  * webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView * textView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Actions

- (IBAction)reloadButtonAction:(id)sender {

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.webfx.com/blog/images/assets/cdn.sixrevisions.com/0435-01_html5_download_attribute_demo/samp/htmldoc.html"]]];

}

- (IBAction)copyButtonAction:(id)sender {

    if ( self.webView.loading ) {

        self.statusLabel.text = @"Loading";

    } else {

        self.statusLabel.text = @"Copying ...";

        [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()"
                   completionHandler: ^ ( id content, NSError * error ) {

            if ( error ) {

                self.statusLabel.text = @"Error";

            } else if ( [content isKindOfClass:NSString.class] ) {

                [UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard setData:[( NSString * ) content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                  forPasteboardType:( NSString * ) kUTTypeHTML];
                self.statusLabel.text = @"Copied HTML";

            } else {

                self.statusLabel.text = @"Unknown type";

            }

        }];

    }

}

- (IBAction)pasteButtonAction:(id)sender {


    if ( [UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard containsPasteboardTypes:@[( NSString * ) kUTTypeHTML]] ) {

        // Convert to attributed string
        NSError * cvtErr;
        NSData  * data = [UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard dataForPasteboardType:( NSString * ) kUTTypeHTML];
        NSAttributedString * attr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                  documentAttributes:NULL
                                           error: & cvtErr];

        if ( cvtErr ) {

            self.statusLabel.text = @"Convert error";

        } else if ( attr ) {

            self.statusLabel.text = @"Attributed";
            self.textView.attributedText = attr;

        } else {

            self.statusLabel.text = @"Unable to decode";

        }

    } else {

        NSString * content = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard.string;

        if ( content ) {

            // Paste plain text
            self.textView.text = content;
            self.statusLabel.text = @"Pasted";

        } else {

            self.statusLabel.text = @"No string content";

        }

    }

}

@end
```

The code is very similar to before. The problem is that HTML = plain text so to copy HTML and retain the style or formatting also depends on the destination app into which you paste it. That destination app needs to handle the HTML correctly for what you want to achieve.

Anyhow, here are the changes from earlier.

On the copy side: the text is now copied as HTML and not as a string. There is very little difference there except that now, unlike before, the string is converted to data and the type is marked as `kUTTypeHTML`.

On the paste side: the real difference is here. If the pasteboard contains HTML then it is retrieved and formatted using an attributed string. It also works fine if you e.g. paste into *Notes* BTW.

This illustrates the problem you are dealing with here. I could just as well have used the code I used earlier and everything would work but in stead of formatted HTML I would get the unformatted / source HTML.

Here I assume that you are interested in fairly simple but formatted *text*. You did not mention *text* specifically and if you e.g. wanted to copy an HTML formatted table then my example is not adequate as I use a `UITextView` as destination.

For more complex HTML I'd use a `WKWebView` as destination as well and set its HTML string to the pasted in HTML, but again, this shows how the destination app also needs to cooperate in handling the HTML correctly.

Finally, looking at the updated answer and your code it is difficult to spot a difference, so I suspect your problem could be earlier with `content` itself in

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setString:(NSString *)content)
```

**UPDATE**

I also looked at the git repository you mention. There I found the following

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(hasString:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  reject:(__unused RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  BOOL stringPresent = YES;
  UIPasteboard *clipboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  if (@available(iOS 10, *)) {
    stringPresent = clipboard.hasStrings;
  } else {
    NSString* stringInPasteboard = clipboard.string;
    stringPresent = [stringInPasteboard length] == 0;
  }

  resolve([NSNumber numberWithBool: stringPresent]);
}
```

It looks wrong, I think that one line should be

```
stringPresent = [stringInPasteboard length] != 0;
```

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn’t what I’m looking for. I already have the HTML string, I want to copy the HTML to the clipboard formatted so that when it is pasted in another application it maintains the style. Changing my existing code to copy as a string does exactly what you’re example shows but much simpler, but that’s not what I’m looking for.

Comment: Ok, but copy and paste a string should not change its formatting or style. The HTML is already formatted / styled and you loose this when you copy and paste? What do you mean by this formatting or style? The indenting? The syntax highlighting? In either case the destination app can reformat as you paste so the clipboard may not be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This pointed me in the right direction!